# Нужна помощь с retofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Впервые использую эту библиотеку. Нужно описать get запрос к апи сайта.
Вот интерфейс

```
public interface Salons {
@GET("api/partners/list")
Call<List<Salon>> getSalons();
```

}

Класс, сгенерированный в http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

```
public class Salon {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("contact_number")
@Expose
private String contactNumber;
@SerializedName("work_days")
@Expose
private List<String> workDays = null;

@SerializedName("logo")
@Expose
private String logo;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}

public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}

public List<String> getWorkDays() {
    return workDays;
}

public void setWorkDays(List<String> workDays) {
    this.workDays = workDays;
}


public String getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

public void setLogo(String logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}
```

}

И сам запрос

```
public void getSalons(){
    final String TAG = "Ответ";
    final String BASE_URL = "http://u1938.blue.elastictech.org/";
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    Salons salons = retrofit.create(Salons.class);

    Call<List<Salon>> salon = salons.getSalons();
    salon.enqueue(new Callback<List<Salon>>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Salon>> call, Response<List<Salon>> response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "response.body().size()");
            Toast.makeText(GetResponce.this, "Получилось", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Salon>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Не получилось");
            Toast.makeText(GetResponce.this, "Не получилось", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Приложение вывело в тост текст из onFailure, то есть  "Не получилось"

Comment: А что в Throwable t?

Comment: Вы не правильно сгенерировали POJO. Скормите генератору всё содержимое ответа сервера - должно получиться три класса (конкретно для этого json'а), все нужно добавить в проект. Тот, что с именем, заданным в поле `Class name` будет корневым - его использовать в качестве `ResponseBody` (там, где у Вас сейчас `List<Salon>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по ответу с [сервиса](http://u1938.blue.elastictech.org/api/partners/list), у вас неправильно описан класс ответа

Должно быть так:

```
public class ResponseData {

   @SerializedName("data")
   @Expose
   public List<Salon> data;

}
```

Соответственно поменяется тип параметра в методе интерфейса:

```
Call<ResponseData> getSalons();
```

И не забудьте про тип в вашем коллбэке:

```
salon.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>(){
   //...
});
```

Comment: Сейчас вроде бы получилось. Не могли бы вы подсказать где у меня находится json, который я (должен был) взять с сервера? Под каким именем мне его искать?

Comment: @ТагирИдрисов, в коллбэке в методе `onResponse` вторым параметром идёт объект `Response<ResponseData> response`. В нём есть метод `body()`, который имеет тип `ResponseData`, он вам и нужен. *P.S. если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его как правильный*